# Hardwired Features of Interpretation

Tags: metaphysics

Recently, I have been posting here, and it concerns mostly with metaphysics.

So:

Is interpretation a hardwired feature of the brain and person?

So, when we see symbols, we AUTOMATICALLY identify it as something we already know, we can't stop this feature.

In other words, we cannot ever stop identifying symbols. As you read this right now, you are identifying symbols, without even thinking about it.

Is that how this works? I posted a similar issue with

"x" and "2x" how the "x"'s could be different physically but have the exact same meaning. This applies here.

Without thinking about it, your brain automatically identifies "x" and "2x" as having the same meaning. Same goes with

"1", and "10," you know they are both "1", the number because you brain automatically identifies it.

So, as a recap, **is there any reason why we interpret the way we do? Or is it simply a hardwired feature, which won't be changed?**

Thanks!

Comment: I'm studying an unconventional math now, and I have to learn those symbols. There is definitely a learning process before the interpretation becomes automatic. Just like learning a new language.

Comment: @GeorgeChen, thanks. I meant, okay SK you learned English, but then you autonaticslly saw symbols and recognized it. So "hello" you thought okay, this is hello, it is hardwired right?

Comment: Learning a word or a symbol consists of forming a habit. A habit permanently changes one's brain. So yes it is hardwired.

Comment: So it is our habit, that leads us to interpretations? Thanks, you have helped me a lot!!

Comment: Yes, but once the interpretation becomes a habit, we don't call it interpretation any more. The response to a word becomes spontaneous.

Comment: @GeorgeChen, so there really is no specific reason for interpreting two instances of pi, the mathematical unit as the same thing, it is simply a hardwired feature isnt it?

Comment: After it becomes a habit, pi needs no more interpretation than "apple."

Comment: @GeorgeChen, thanks a lot for the reply, it helps very much. Why am I so susceptible to not accepting details? It's hard for me to accept things. As a philosophist, would you mind telling me how I can get into the habits of accepting things?

Comment: You have a pretty good mental habit. I'm not going to tell you to change that.

Comment: @GeorgeChen, really? Is that why I get downvotes on every single question? Even here, (-1), I just wonder why. I honestly doubt my thinking capabilities, they're just obsessive, and people just downvote all the time. Anyway, these things are regular actions. Like interpretation, I always took an looking-like-apple shape to be an Apple, without **every thinking why,** then I think it is wrong to question this feature, given to us before birth isnt it?

Comment: I dont like down vote either, but be prepared that in philosophy people generally disagree with each other. Regarding the apple, there was a learning process. But I am nobody, dont take my answer too serious. You can indulge your meditation a little bit, and write down your thoughts in a notebook. Dont let down votes disturb your peace of mind. you sound like on the right track to me.

Comment: @GeorgeChen, my ultimate goal is to be a mathematician, not a philosopher. Ever. Can you read the last comment oI wrotee to jobermark, and tell me what you think as last thoughts.

Comment: Given the type of questions you ask, for originality's sake, I dont recommend you read any philosophy. You just meditate your own question and find out the answer by observing your own thoughts. Descartes did that. He read very little.

Comment: @GeorgeChen, I think I'll interpret the way I always used to. I am pretty sure no one questions that capability.

Comment: It does not always work. In type theory, symbols are typically ambiguous. Depending on their types, similar symbols may have totally different meanings. For example,  Λ and the one in {Λ} are totally different things. I digress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure an evolutionary argument gives a 'reason' in the sense you are asking.  If it does, the answer to your questions is "Yes, both."  Our strong leanings toward capturing simple symbols is just a hardwired mechanism, but it is shaped that way for a reason.

Most of modern experimental psychology would say that we reach out for symbols, and we capture them and then fit them into a context.  (Though it requires a very broad sense of 'symbol'.)  Our perception does not receive data passively and collate it, but instead projects forward assumptions to meet the incoming data half-way.

For instance, we begin to have emotional reactions before we identify their causes, and then shape the emotional experience to fit the cause.  We screen out highly intrusive, obvious and outright scary data when we are acutely focused on something difficult.

Most strikingly to me, we invent object permanence.  If we see identical things in two different places in our vision too quickly in succession, we see them as the same thing, we invent a continuous path between them in our vision, and we remember it as real.  If the objects are seen in different orientations or in different colors, we think we can remember the exact point in our visual field where 'it' changed color or flipped over, even though 'it' was two different objects, and neither of them was ever in that position.

One way to make sense of this is via evolution.  It makes sense that a general reasoning method evolved from a system originally tuned to a narrow range of targets or threats, sought or avoided situations, and not from some more general mechanism that just 'tried to make sense' of the world.  As we developed subtler, less pointed goals, we began to see symbols instead of threats or targets.  We started to piece our stimuli together into more and more complete packages, and to be less intensely motivated by specific details most of the time.  But the basic methodology of scanning for known objects still dominates its structure.

So the theory is that we are not born to learn how to notice two "x" marks as the same thing, but we are born to learn things like how to know two ripe apples as the same thing, or two prowling cats as the same thing, and we have leveraged that for more general purposes.

Once you become attached to this, it is hard to see how other ways learning might evolve would be anywhere near as efficient.  It is clearly not the only way of thinking.  Many of our more artificial, explicit ways of thinking work directly opposite to this, trying to get the overall sense and not attach to detail or goal first.  Resisting the impulse to pre-judge is a primary path to fairness, and whole religions have grow up with that focus.  But it seems likely that most of the ways evolution would lead to a brain, would contain some aspect of this bias, since focus on danger is a basic mechanism for survival.

At the risk of continually over-promoting the same book, "Consciousness, Explained" contains this data and the argument much more detail.  Dennett lays it out as motivation for his favorite theory of learning, and to make counterarguments to older theories.

Comment: I wrote this above to; so there really is no specific reason for interpreting two instances of pi, the mathematical unit as the same thing, it is simply a hardwired feature isnt it?

Comment: That was too long:  Basically, we are wired to err on the side of assuming symbols mean more than they do, and taking them apart slowly, rather than starting from a pattern and building up evidence for them.  That works well for pi, it works less well for apples, or people.  We do learn that difference.  So not as much is determined as you seem to believe.

Comment: Our hardwired feature is designed to fail, to overestimate the power of a name.  And when it fails we hand things over to more subtle processes.  But in the case of math, it doesn't fail as expected, and we get very attached to those symbols.

Comment: True. Thanks for replying. One more thing: Before this, I never thought about such things, I just did things, without conconsciously thinking why, such as interpreting symbols. I just interpreted symbols, similar looking to have the same meaning. Like "pi," I just took a similar looking shape to mean the same thing, "pi." Maybe, it is better to not question it, and continue it. In the end, does it really have an actual, concrete reason anyway? Thanks1

Comment: In my book, insofar as the mind is like he brain, it has many layers, each subtler than the last.  To the extent lower functions serve you, it does not make sense to bicker with them.  But each new layer exists just because the previous one fails at some things.  All one can really say about this, in my opinion, is that when proceeding one way fails you, do not insist upon it.

Comment: a question. So we don't know WHY we interpret something some way, we just DO IBTRTPRET IT?

Comment: What do you mean by 'why'...  

You have a good 'why' from a basic philosophy point of view in the other answer -- language makes the mind optimize  for a specific way of learning instead of other ways, because that provides a more efficient use of language over time.

And you have a good 'why' from a materialist point of view in this one -- symbol interpretation is our new use for animals' old threat-identifying responses, so it is one of the first things we do with information, because that used to be really urgent.

What sort of answer were you looking for?

Comment: In any given instance, we interpret as we do because we have done so in the past, and not had that contradicted.  From an evolutionary point of view symbolization is our default, first-string intellectual action.  When that is contradicted, we have operant conditioning.  When that is inadequate, we have conscious analysis.  When that does not converge we have more abstract ways of theorizing that involve visualization...  (These correspond vaguely to different layers of the brain.)

Comment: I suppose you are right with this. Ultimately **perfection can never be achieved, and nothing can be copied verbatim**. So what people here propose is that if we don't suppose symbols (a little off) to mean the same thing then we as a human species will not get anywhere, and get nothing done? Thanks!

Comment: Not really.  Folks are not saying this is the only way this can get done.  But it is a way that we evolved into, and that our form of language supports.  We do question symbol identity -- a lot of people see faces in rocks all the time, and dismiss their (automatic) interpretation of those as faces.  [If you can't dismiss this, you become schizophrenic in a certain way, because the world literally seems to be watching you.]  But the less we question it, since it is our basic process, the faster we tend to proceed.  Perfection might well go down a different path than efficiency.

Comment: I think I'll interpret the way I always used to. I am pretty sure no one questions that capability. I mean, Okay. Let's think this **once and for all**, please answer: **so, there is no reason for actually interpreting the closest figure to what you know?** thanks!

Comment: Answer my question and I will answer yours.  What is wrong with the two answers given?  What on Earth do you mean by 'why' if these two answers are not seen as reasons 'why' we do this?

Comment: I do apologize a lot actually, maybe it is my obsessive habits, which is causing this. There is **nothing wrong** with the two answers given. They are excellent. But it's just that, all I want was a recap. I apologise for this.

But the reason you point out is evolution if I am correct?

Comment: Yes.  I think both of thes answers come down to some sort of evolution, and adaptation to the environment.  Mine is about what part of our brain does this, and how important that was to previous species, compared to the parts of the brain that accomplish similar things in other ways.  The other is about what predispositions in the way we learn helps children learn language efficiently.  So both of these are about how we fit into a larger system that has shaped us to prefer this approach.  But we are both saying it is inborn for reasons of survival.

Comment: I think we have had an excellent conversation, I will choose your answer because you have helped me the most here. Can I ask one more thing please? We also follow this because perfection cannot be achieved right? This is all built on **trust** isn't it? That we trust the author isn't tricking you.

Comment: Maybe this is just vocabulary, but I would say no.  We might **accept** the interpretation on those terms, but it is not why the interpretation is **made**.  Those people who see faces in rocks learn to ignore them, but the **interpretation** is already there.  Reflexes don't make decisions for us.

Comment: thanks. I'll say something else now. I never questioned this before. So, do humans interpret without thinking why they interpreted things that way? Such as symbols/

Comment: Certainly.  Identifying an image with a symbol is usually automatic.  If you consider deeper, pre-literate symbols like faces, snakes or spiders, it seems obvious.  People can develop phobias of things they have never encountered in real life, but only as images.  Surely they would never choose to do so.  Something in the image triggers a deeper connection to the thing symbolized, without he person getting to think "Is that really a spider, or just a picture of one?"

Comment: you have been of great great great help. Do you think it is wise to just continue doing an action without a conscious reason? Like before even thinking about this question? Thanks!

Comment: I am a fan of pursuing expertise.  It is wise, in my estimation, to consider whether what you are doing is working for you and everyone else, but not get into what computer engineers call 'analysis paralysis'.  Conscious justification of things is a way of addressing difficulties, not successes.  I think the physical construction of the brain, which is basically two copies of one kind of animal brain wrapped around another one, suggests this.

Comment: The more evolved part only works on stuff the more animal part is not sure of.  And even then, the right half, which has no direct connection to speech, and remains largely hidden, is the half that handles setbacks, while the half more free to really act (since it controls the internal monologue) is strongly biased toward positive data.  So your brain itself suggests that conscious processing is a rare resource that should be used primarily on fixing things that are broken.

Comment: exactly, I do not want to have analysis paralysis, which is what I am trying to get away from totally. Exactly. Will you agree: There are some things you do without a conscious reason, I suppose this is one! Isn't it?

Comment: please, you are my only help!!

Comment: Surely.  Most things you do you do without a conscious reason.  I am going to stop answering the same question over and over again.

Comment: sorry for my obsessive tendencies. You have been the biggest help here. Same goes with assumptions right? You make assumptions without conscious reasons in communication? Thanks1

Comment: apologies. Perhaps you may need a break from me.

Answer (score 1):

According to Relevance Theory, our cognitive system is hard-wired to search out relevance.

Something has relevance for us if it causes us to update our stock of assumptions in some way. This can be through us adding to it or by strengthening, weakening or eliminating one of our existing assumptions. One particularly rich way of updating is when some stimulus combines with an existing assumption leading us to infer a new one that we wouldn't be able to get from just the old assumption or the stimulus alone.

In actual fact, most stimuli which affect us in this way may be doing several of these things at the same time. So it starting to rain may cause Pamela to cancel her assumption that she's going to have lunch in the park, will combine with her assumption that her washing's on the line at home so that she infers that it's going to be wet when she goes back, will strengthen her assumption that she's going to need a beer after a horrible day at work and so forth.

What we have discussed so far isn't a good measure of relevance on its own. The reason is that there's a payoff to be had between informativity and the amount of cognitive effort (whether conscious or not) required to process any kind of input. So the more effort we have to expend, and the longer it takes us, the relatively less valuable that same stimulus is to us. Relevance then can be though of as how much bang you get for your buck, how much updating you get per unit of effort spent processing it.

When we communicate, we exploit each other's cognitive drive for relevance. In order to decode what someone's communicative intention is, we have to use all the clues we can get from the context in order to build a reading of what someone is intending to communicate. This goes on even at the most minute level. So for example, when someone says *Bob's been arrested*, we need a theory about who the intended referent of *Bob* actually is. There are, after all, millions of people whom *Bob* could refer to. Normally, however, the speaker, who wishes to affect your stock of assumptions efficiently without wasting effort of their part, will give you exactly the right amount of linguistically encoded clues for you to be able to identify their intended meaning from the context.

As a listener, you will automatically opt for the most informative reading that takes the least effort. So with regard to the sentence above, you'll automatically exclude from the potential *Bob*s any who you don't have reason to believe that you both know. People you've already been talking about, or who you both live or work with are more likely to be the intended referent. Effectively you will take the path of least resistance when trying to identify them. After all, if the speaker had intended you to scan your memory for obscure Bob's they'd have given you more specific information to make the assignment of the reference less difficult/effort consuming.

The upshot of all of this, is that whenever we engage with any linguistic type of encoding, our relevance search engine gets into gear. Its general operational mode is that of looking for the greatest informativity with the least effort - in order to understand the communicative intent of the 'speaker' (writer, or whoever). This means that when you see a couple of symbols repeated, you're cognitive system will make the inferences that are the least costly and fit with a potential communicative intent on the part of the speaker. So if we see two symbols (signs of communicative intent), we are going to interpret them as if they mean the same thing. Our cognitive system will assume that if they were intended to signify something different from each other, this would be indicated by the speaker, who after all wants their input to be relevant to us (otherwise they wouldn't bother to provide it in the first place). Also, if we see a symbol and recognise it as indicating a communicative intention, we will immediately start to process it to derive what relevance we can. The path of least resistance to us will always be to process symbols that we recognise as being exactly those symbols that we recognise!.

Not sure how clear any of that is, but that's my relevance theoretic  attempt at an explanation!

Comment: This is basically the same answer, it just focuses on how things work rather than how they got that way -- different interpretations of 'why'...